# Override jquery mobile field contain select menu CSS

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I want to modify the width of the jquery mobile select menu. I did the same with the input texts fields creating a new class called **cod1** and setting the label width to 25% and input field to 55%:

```css
.cod1 label.ui-input-text { vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;  width: 25%;  margin: 0 2% 0 0; }
.cod1 input.ui-input-text, 
.cod1 textarea.ui-input-text, 
.cod1 .ui-input-search { width: 55%; display: inline-block; }
```

Now I want to do the same thing with the select menu but in the jquerymobile css file, this properties are inside a @media, and I don't know how this works:

```css
@media all and (min-width: 450px){  
.ui-field-contain label.ui-select { vertical-align: top;  display: inline-block;  width: 20%;  margin: 0 2% 0 0; }
.ui-field-contain .ui-select { width: 60%; display: inline-block; }
}
```

I tried to override this to modify the width using my cod1 class but it doesn't work. The only way I've been successful to modify the width has been modifying the original CSS file directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the answer of this question explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781957/jqm-jquerymobile-custom-css-for-invalid-select?rq=1), the select, checkbox and radio elements are completely replaced by jquery mobile.

The answer to my question is really simple, just ignore the field-contain:

```css
.cod1 label.ui-select { width:25%; }
.cod1 .ui-select { width:55%; }
```

[JQM (jQueryMobile) custom css for invalid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781957/jqm-jquerymobile-custom-css-for-invalid-select?rq=1)

Comment: WOW! What an Answer, I Liked the way you came up with the solution :(